# Possible Javascript bug?

Tags: javascript, firefox

Here's the code sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <script>
            i = 0
            while(i < 500)
            {
                date = new Date()
                console.log(i, ' ', date);
                date.setHours(5)
                i++  
            }

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

The firebug console eventually outputs the date set at 5 hours rather than the original, unaltered date. I've only tested this on Firefox 17.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

console.log is not asynchronous, it is simply dynamic. When you log the date object using the comma notation, you are logging a live reference to that date object, so when it updates, so does the console display. If you logged using toString instead, the value would not change :

```
console.log("logging date as string, i : " i + " date : " + date);
```

Comment: Yeah, I've compared the two and it seems you're right. Still, a rather bizarre way of handling things. Definitely something to watch out for in the future!

Answer (score 4):

That would depend on the browser's implementation of `console.log`. As far as I know, browsers have an asynchronous `console.log` function which would also be the case for Chrome. Execution for asynchronous functions is only when the browser is not doing stuff.

```
while (i < 500) {
    date = new Date()
    console.log(i, ' ', date); //this set aside
    date.setHours(5); //this executed first instead
    i++;
}
```

To prove that `console.log` is the one to blame, [I have this code](http://tinker.io/a303d) which outputs the result into the DOM instead of using `console.log` and it shows it right.

```
i = 0
while (i < 500) {
    date = new Date()
    $('body').append('<div>'+i+':'+date+'</div>');
    date.setHours(5);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: That would make sense, except that I didn't find this by running console.log, but rather through bug hunting in my own code. Now, granted, that might be set async as well, but that doesn't make a any sense, more so if I specifically create a new date object.

Comment: Chrome used to have the same 'problem' (async console.log), but at least v24 shows the original date on console (FF19 doesn't).